# Lua's "Generic For Loop" for Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, lua

So, I've been searching endlessly for something similiar to Lua's "Generic For Loop" in Python.

I've been working on a simple text based game in Python, and I've been working with dictionaries a lot.

Here is something I'm looking for (in Lua):

```
Dictionary = {
"Red" = "There is some red paint on the walls.",
"Green" = "There is a little bit of green paint on the floor.",
}

for i, v in pairs(Dictionary) do
print(i, v)
end
```

What this will do is, go through the dictionary, then print out the INDEX and the VALUE. How would I do something like this in Python?

I know there is this:

`for i in Dictionary:
     print(i)`

But that just prints the INDEX. I would like to access both the INDEX and the VALUE. Something like:

```
for i, v in Dictionary:
    print(i, v)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`items`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items). Iterating over a dict just gives you the keys, so you'd have to do:

```
for key in my_dict:
    x = my_dict[key]
```

What you want is this:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    # do something
```

Comment: Don't name your variables `dict`, please? Encouraging name-stomping the built-ins in new users is mean.

Comment: Stepped away shortly after writing this. I prefixed it.

Answer (score 3):

two ways:

```
for i, v in Dictionary.items():
    print(i, v) #outputs pairs as key value
for tup in Dictionary.items(): #same thing
    print(tup) # outputs pairs as (key,value)
```

or

```
for key in Dictionary:
    print(key,Dictionary[key])
```

EDIT RESPONSE TO COMMENT:

```
>>> d = {1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4}
>>> for item in d.items(): print(item)

(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
>>> for key,val in d.items(): print(key,val) 

1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

this is because in the first loop, `item` is a tuple and the `__repr__` for a tuple has the brackets and commas as part of it where as the second loop splits the tuple into two seperate variables. `print` then automatically adds a space delimiter in between each parameter passed in the print function.

As explained by Two-Bit Alchemist:

> In case it's not entirely clear still, in the tup formulation you'd access the key and value as tup[0] and tup[1], respectively. for key, val in my_dict.items(): ... and for tup in my_dict.items(): key, val = tup is the same setup. The point is you can use tuple unpacking just fine inline in a for loop.

Comment: May I ask, for your "tup" example, is tup holding both the index and the value?

Comment: yes, it is a tuple of both values. check the edit for what i mean

Comment: In case it's not entirely clear still, in the `tup` formulation you'd access the key and value as `tup[0]` and `tup[1]`, respectively. `for key, val in my_dict.items(): ...` and `for tup in my_dict.items(): key, val = tup` is the same setup. The point is you can use [tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) just fine inline in a `for` loop.

Comment: ty @Two-BitAlchemist, i copied your comment onto the post for clarity

Answer (score 1):

The `items` method (or in Py2, `viewitems` or `iteritems` to avoid making a whole new `list` containing copies of the `dict` key/value pairs) is the way to go:

```
for k, v in Dictionary.items():  # For performance, use .viewitems() on Py2.7, .items() on Py3.x
    print(k, v)
```